# Show that $2^{341}\equiv2\pmod{341}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that $2^{341}\equiv2\pmod{341}$

---

My work:

Prime factorization of $341 = 31\cdot11$, thus $2^{11\cdot31}\equiv2\pmod{31\cdot11}$

$2^{341} = 2=2(2^{340}-1)$, we have $2^{340}\equiv1\pmod{341}$

$2^{340}=4^{175}=1024^{35}$

$1024\equiv1\pmod{341}$

$1024^{35}\equiv1^{35}\pmod{341}$

$(4^5)^{35}\equiv1\pmod{341}$

$2^{340}\equiv1\pmod{341}$

Am I right??

---

And someone please teach me how to use Fermat little theorem to prove this problem, please...

---

Comment: This looks right, but I will strongly warn you against writing "We have" and then stating the thing that you are trying to prove. I understand what you are saying, but it would be better to just write the computation from the left column rather than starting with the equality that you're asked to derive.

Comment: My second comment is: Have you learned Fermat's Little Theorem (or, even better, Euler's theorem)? If so, it seems that the intention of the question was for you to use the result of that theorem.

Comment: I know that but i dont know how to use it. So i just kind of work my way around using this dumb proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $\rm\: mod\ 341\!:\ (2^{10})^{34}\!\equiv 1024^{34}\equiv(1+3\cdot 341)^{34}\!\equiv 1^{34}\!\equiv 1,\ $ so $\rm\ 2^{340}\!\equiv 1\:\Rightarrow\:2^{341}\!\equiv 2\cdot 1$

**Remark** $\ $ Or you could note $\rm\: 2^5\! =32 \equiv \pm1\,\ (mod\ 31,11)\:\Rightarrow\ 2^{10}\!\equiv 1\ (mod\ 31\cdot 11)$

More generally $\rm\ b\mid a^k\!-1,\ c\mid a^k\!+1\:\Rightarrow\:bc\mid a^{2k}\!-1\mid a^{2kn}\!-1$

said modularly $\ \ \begin{eqnarray}\rm a^k&\equiv&\rm \ \ \ 1\,\  (mod\ b)\\ \rm a^k&\equiv&\rm -1\,\ (mod\ c)\end{eqnarray}\rm\,\ \Rightarrow\ \ a^{2kn}\equiv 1\,\ (mod\ bc)$

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Observe that 341 = 11 * 31.

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)
$$2^{340} \bmod 11 \equiv 2^{10*34} \bmod 11 \equiv 1^34 \bmod 11 \equiv 1 \bmod 11$$
$$2^{340} \bmod 31 \equiv 2^{30 * 10 + 10} \bmod 31 \equiv 2^10 \bmod 31 \equiv 32^2 \bmod 31 \equiv 1 \bmod 31$$

$1 \bmod 341$ is one such solution, and it is unique in the integers mod 341 (again by Chinese Remainder Theorem).